# Find a function satisfy certain condition

Tags: functions, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

Find function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(2)=2$ and 
$$\sum_{i=1}^nc_i\frac{\partial(x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2)^{\frac{f(y)}{2}}}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial(x_1^2+\dots+x^2_n)^{\frac{f(y)}{2}}}{\partial y}$$

---

This is what I got so far, firstly I tried to simplify the expression

$$\sum_{i=1}^n2c_ix_i\frac{f(y)}{2}(x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2)^{\frac{f(y)}{2}-1}
=\frac{1}{2}\ln(x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2)(x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2)^{\frac{f(y)}{2}}f'(y)$$

Not sure it's right, but still can't find $f$ satisfy this condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such function.

Writing $r^2=\sum_i x_i^2$ and using the fact that $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_i}=\frac{x_i}{r}$ we can rewrite the above equation equivalently as

$$f(y)r^{f(y)-2}\sum_{i}c_i x_i=f'(y)\ln r~ r^{f(y)}\iff f(y)\sum_{i}c_i x_i=f'(y)r^2\ln r$$

but clearly the last equation cannot be satisfied for a function $f(y)$. If we allowed other dependences maybe this could be done. This can also be done as long as we restrict the domain on a surface

$$A~r^2\ln r=\sum_{i}{c_ix_i}~,~ A\in \mathbb{R}$$

in which case the solution is

$$f(y)=2e^{A(y-2)}$$

but whether this is useful or not depends on the nature of the original problem posed.